# json issue with google apis and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

Hey I have following code which gives me an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

My code:

```
    $.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference="+ref_tel+"&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY&callback=?",
       function(data){

}, "json");
```

What's wrong?

P.S. the JSON looks like below:

```
    {
  "html_attributions" : [],
  "result" : {
    "address_components" : [
      {
        "long_name" : "48",
        "short_name" : "48",
        "types" : [ "street_number" ]
      },
      {
        "long_name" : "Pirrama Road",
        "short_name" : "Pirrama Road",
        "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
        "long_name" : "Pyrmont",
        "short_name" : "Pyrmont",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
        "long_name" : "NSW",
        "short_name" : "NSW",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
        "long_name" : "AU",
        "short_name" : "AU",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      },
      {
        "long_name" : "2009",
        "short_name" : "2009",
        "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address" : "5/48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont NSW, Australia",
    "formatted_phone_number" : "(02) 9374 4000",
    "geometry" : {
      "location" : {
        "lat" : -33.8669710,
        "lng" : 151.1958750
      }
    },
    "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
    "id" : "4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
    "international_phone_number" : "+61 2 9374 4000",
    "name" : "Google Sydney",
    "rating" : 4.60,
    "reference" : "CnRlAAAAAfV6JIqSzL8Cf4VnXn0EaI1d5k3IPhdkEonq0MxiUbQFFSVuptVbXbNH4mrevb0bc7G8yWqTUv76i4KTuO_Wf3OrRHjCJJwzQ0mNLjbYGSVqy2eqyrgOUkl6S_sJfTbHzWZYrfPy7KZaet0mM5S6thIQJYuy5v_JD--ZxXEJLWTQRRoU5UaciXBBo89K-bce18Ii9RsEIws",
    "types" : [ "store", "establishment" ],
    "url" : "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=10281119596374313554",
    "vicinity" : "5/48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
    "website" : "http://www.google.com.au/"
  },
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

And debugger shows Me that the error is on line 2. Can someone fix this?

Comment: This is not a great way to ask a question. Do you have any more information about the error? A line number maybe? Did you have it working before you made some change? It might be the ? at the end of your URL?

Comment: The ? is used by jquery to append a callback function name for the JSONP request.

Comment: can you see the response in the firebug or fiddler or chrome developer tools

Comment: Here U are, the response looks like I show, and debugger shows an error on line 2: "html_attributions" : [],

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps [Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceDetails) doesn't seem to support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Thus you are not able to use it at the client-side (Also you will expose your API key if put it somewhere in the source code).

By the way, your code throws an error because of

```
{
  "something" : value
}
```

is interpreted as block of code (a statement) instead of an object (an expression). Javascript has labels with the following syntax:

```
labelName : statement
```

But only identifier may be used as a label name. String (or, more generally, any expression) can not. This results in a syntax error.